# Exporting actual size of UV Layout

Tags: export, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

Let's take for example

- There's a soda can in the UV Editor
- I selected and unwrapped the vertical sides of the soda can in the Edit Mode.
- In the UV map visualiser on the left, the unwrapped map has a width pretty much longer than its height
- I try to export the UV Layout as a png so I can make proper Label adjustment in Photoshop
- But the trick here is, the size on the right shows "1920 X 1076". Having adjusted the numbers (larger) so it might fit the whole layout size, the exported layout still reverts to the default "1920 X 1076", at that cutting away the actual width of the Layout.

I am conflicted. What do I do to get/export the actual unwrapped UV Map width/size as shown when I unwrapped it?[image]